# Update MySQL version from 5.1 to 5.5 in CentOS 6.2

Tags: mysql, database, centos

I tried to update MySQL from 5.1 to 5.5 in CentOS 6.2. The following is the process I did:

```
1. rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm
2. yum install libmysqlclient15 --enablerepo=webtatic
3. yum remove mysql mysql-*
4. yum install mysql55 mysql55-server --enablerepo=webtatic
```

When I tried the 4th step, I got the following output:

```
[root@d2005 /]# yum install mysql55 mysql55-server --enablerepo=webtatic
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: yum.singlehop.com
 * extras: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * updates: pubmirrors.reflected.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql55.x86_64 0:5.5.10-1.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql55-libs = 5.5.10-1.w5 for package: mysql55-5.5.10-1.w5.x86_64
---> Package mysql55-server.x86_64 0:5.5.10-1.w5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: mysql55-server-5.5.10-1.w5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql55-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.10-1.w5 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.013-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.61-1.el6_2.1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mysql55-libs-5.5.10-1.w5.x86_64 conflicts mysql-libs < 5.5.10
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mysql55-libs conflicts with mysql-libs
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

### To list Old MySql

```
yum list installed | grep -i mysql
```

### To remove Old MySql

```
yum remove mysql mysql-*
```

### Remi Dependency on CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

### Install MySQL server

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install mysql mysql-server
```

### To list New MySql

```
yum list installed | grep -i mysql
```

### start MySql server

`/etc/init.d/mysqld start` ## use restart after update

### OR

`service mysqld start` ## use restart after update

```
chkconfig --levels 235 mysqld on
```

### Last

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Now my MySql version is 5.5.32

## Ref:

http://www.webtatic.com/packages/mysql55/

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Hope it help some one

**NOTE:**
    Adding comments from @pim (in comments)

```
Just wanted to add that after the upgrade, my crontab was removed as well. Had to reinstall with "yum install vixie-cron" (CentOS 6)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same problem as the OP. Instead of upgrading mysql-libs to the latest version, it believes **mysql55-libs** and **mysql-libs** are unrelated and conflict with one another.

If you remove the previous versions of MySQL first, will that zap your datadir, ibdata1, /etc/my.cnf, logs, etc. and/or directory structures in general?

Comment: I forgot for what server I did this...  You should take the backup of databases you have also log you have..  I dont think you will have them after you upgrade...

Comment: I am going to try [these steps](http://blog.iphoting.com/blog/2012/06/19/upgrading-to-mysql-5-dot-5-on-centos-6/) tonight. I will see if yum's `replace` combined with `--replace-with` will let me skip `yum remove`.

Comment: Ok.. if it succeed please add your answer to this question.. that will sure help others...

Comment: **Edited** link _download.fedora.redhat.com_ has been an alias in DNS for link _dl.fedoraproject.org_ and is no more valid. The 'yum' command should **install** and not just **list** the package files. Also, added suggestion to look at current mysql installation, if any, before updating it.

Comment: Upgrade mysql to 5.5.37, and needn't backup database at all. Just let others guy know.

Comment: I was a little hesitant because I was doing this on a live  server, but the above instructions work perfectly. I would first add the Remi Dependency and then remove the old MySQL server, saves you a few seconds :) Bottomline: all it took was about 1 minute of downtime, the MySQL data was still present and after the update (from 5.1.73 to 5.5.47), the site ran perfectly again.

Comment: Just wanted to add that after the upgrade, my crontab was removed as well. Had to reinstall with "yum install vixie-cron" (CentOS 6)

Comment: No good. The part where you're removing the old mysql removed much more than just mysql. Had to reinstall the server.

Comment: Now `plesk` doesnt work! im missing `plesk-mysql-server.x86_64` and `mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64` was missing, reinstalled it but still on `5.1`

Answer (score 28):

I used the following commands to add a new YUM repo and make the update:

**Download the Remi repo**

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi.repo
```

**Install/Update the mysql version**

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql-server
```

OR

```
yum --enablerepo=remi update mysql-server
```

Comment: No Problem, I had to make the upgrade yesterday and didn't want to uninstall the old version. Uninstalling it via yum prompted me to also uninstall the depending packages like php-mysql and phpMyAdmin, so this way I was able to just update without uninstalling first. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Worked a treat, but for some reason my phpinfo isn't showing the upgrade, yet phpmyadmin does.

Comment: Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/latest/remi/mirror error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: remi

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It's easy and it works! +1

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Drahcir

Answer (score 6):

You appear to have been using the wrong Webtatic Yum repository version than the one for your version of CentOS. See http://www.webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/ for details

e.g.

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

You can use a yum plugin made by the IUS community to switch mysql-libs with mysql55w-libs. (the following assuming you still use Webtatic)

```
yum install mysql yum-plugin-replace
yum replace mysql --replace-with mysql55w
```

That should allow you to replace mysql with mysql55w-libs, whilst maintaining the older libmysqlclient for any dependencies.

If you see other packages than mysql being removed, then be careful, as they might be needed, but using this method, I've found to be reliable whenever I've used it.

I'm posting this solution as Remi's repository is not always the ideal solution. This method is more complex, but would never cause you to accidentally update your entire web stack by using repositories that use package names matching base distribution packages.

Comment: Thank you Andy, this is old answer, the repo urls could be wrong..  Thank you once again for giving us the correct url..:)

Answer (score 6):

## 2015/08/19 -  For those of you working on older (but still decent) hardware with a matching OS (typically 32 bit machines).

### -- This will upgrade to mysql 5.6 community not 5.5 --

This worked for me after some research and mixing/matching/testing the answers found on various page of the internet (mainly from this page and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html).
My OS shipped with mysql 5.1, I wanted to have 5.6.

### My system

```
[root@host]# cat /etc/*release 
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
[root@host]# uname -a
Linux host 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Thu Aug 13 19:58:36 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@host]# arch
i686
```

This is installed on a 2006 mac pro 1.1 (CPUs upgraded to 3.0GHz Intel Xeon X5365 Quad-Core).

#### Commands I ran

This was done almost immediately after a fresh install of the OS and system update via yum

#### list mysql currently installed

```
yum list installed | grep -i mysql
```

#### remove installed msql

```
yum remove mysql mysql-*
```

#### list mysql currently installed

```
yum list installed | grep -i mysql
```

#### Download rpm containing mysql 5.6

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm
```

#### Install mysql

```
rpm -Uvh mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql mysql-server
```

#### list mysql currently installed

```
yum list installed | grep -i mysql
```

#### ensure mysql starts on reboot

```
chkconfig --list mysqld
sudo chkconfig mysqld on
chkconfig --list mysqld
```

#### Start mysql

```
service mysqld start
service mysqld status
```

### Result

```
[root@host]# yum list installed | grep -i mysql
compat-mysql51.i686     5.1.54-1.el6.remi @remi                                 
mysql-community-client.i686
                        5.6.26-2.el6      @mysql56-community                    
mysql-community-common.i686
                        5.6.26-2.el6      @mysql56-community                    
mysql-community-libs.i686
                        5.6.26-2.el6      @mysql56-community                    
mysql-community-release.noarch
mysql-community-server.i686
                        5.6.26-2.el6      @mysql56-community                    
perl-DBD-MySQL.i686     4.013-3.el6       @base


[root@host]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26, for Linux (i686) using  EditLine wrapper
```

### mysql config (I did not touch this yet but the info seems legit)

Some interesting basic but efficient performance tuning for mysql:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-5-6-from-official-yum-repositories

### Good luck!

## Edit

I had some issues creating users and granting permissions, this how it was fixed.

#### Error

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'plugin' in 'mysql.user'
```

#### Fix

1. Logged on the server as root
2. Connected to mysql with a simple `mysql`
3. Checked the outcome of this statement: `SELECT COUNT(1) column_count FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';`  The result was 39, 43 is expected for mysql 5.6
4. Issued this statement to update the root password: `update mysql.user set Password=PASSWORD('root') where User='root';`
5. (Logged off mysql with `exit`)
6. Restarted mysql with: `service mysqld restart`
7. Ran: `mysql_upgrade -uroot -proot --force`
8. Reconnected to mysql with `mysql -uroot -proot`
9. Checked the outcome of this statement: `SELECT COUNT(1) column_count FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='mysql' AND table_name='user';`  The result was 43 as expected for mysql 5.6. I was then able to create my users and grant permissions as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Above replies didn't work for me (got this error - error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.tyukGy: not an rpm package).

I followed these steps -

```
## Remove existing/old MySQL ##
yum remove mysql mysql-*
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /var/log/mysql*

## Install Remi Repository on RHEL/CentOS 6.7-6.0 ##
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm 

## Install Remi Repository on RHEL/CentOS 5.4-5.0 ##
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm

yum --enablerepo=remi list mysql mysql-server
yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql mysql-server
```

Taken from - http://www.tecmint.com/install-mysql-on-rhel-centos-6-5-fedora-17-12/

By doing above, i uninstalled MySQL 5.0.* and replaced it with this -

```
[root@localhost]# /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p version
/usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.5.28, for Linux on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version      5.5.28
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:         32 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 3  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 33  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 26  Queries per second avg: 0.093
[root@localhost]#
```

My CentOS version -

```
[root@localhost]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
[root@localhost]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 6 23:43:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Worked great for me after failing with the `mysql-libs` clash

Comment: you should note doing `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql` **WILL** remove all databases.

Answer (score 3):

Use CentOS-Release-SCL is better and easy.

[The Software Collections ( SCL ) Repository](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL)

```
# yum install centos-release-SCL
# yum install mysql55-mysql-server
```

Done.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://blog.iphoting.com/blog/2012/06/19/upgrading-to-mysql-5-dot-5-on-centos-6/) helped me upgrade from MySQL 5.5.15 to 5.5.28. That upgrade also had the problem with `mysql-libs` clashing with `mysql55-libs`.

Comment: I had trouble with the libraries again and used `yum upgrade mysql55-libs --downloadonly; rpm -e mysql-libs --nodeps; rpm -Uvh /var/cache/yum/<REPO>/mysql55-libs;`, where <REPO> is whatever repo you downloaded the package from.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d  http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi.repo
yum --enablerepo=remi -y install mysql-server
OR
yum --enablerepo=remi -y update mysql-server
```