# Best way to install MySQL 5.6 on Centos 6.4

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, rpm, yum

I just installed Centos 6.4, and installed MySQL using the version that came with the Centos distribution.  To my dismay, it is MySQL 5.1.69 versus the current 5.6.12.  As stated on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/linux-installation-native.html, "the MySQL version will often be some way behind the currently available release", but I didn't expect that long.

```
[root@centosBox ~]# rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
mysql-devel-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
[root@centosBox ~]# whereis mysql
mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib64/mysql /usr/include/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
[root@centosBox ~]#
```

An alternative is to install by RPM packages which is the "recommended way to install MySQL" per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/linux-installation-rpm.html. I have done so and it wasn't overly complicated, however, I am concerned as I've often been told that I should always install by yum when available.  Towards the very end of the documentation, it does describe doing so extremely briefly using yum, however, it is so brief that I question whether it is the way to go.

So....  What is the best way for a not guru Linux user to install/upgrade MySQL on a Centos machine?

Comment: after `yum install mysql` did you do `yum update` and `yum upgrade`?

Comment: @Fischer.  Yes, I did do `yum update`, not not `yum upgrade`.  Did the later after getting your comment, but no change.

Comment: i think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361720/update-mysql-version-from-5-1-to-5-5-in-centos-6-2) is the only solution

Comment: @Fischer `yum install MySQL-server-5.6.11-2.el6x86_64.rpm` seems to take.

Comment: What repositories did you use? What is the URL? I have found nothing listed for Enterprise Linux in any the documents above, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit off-topic but there we go.

It is recommended to install from the repositories because you can later update your software to a newer version with a simple `yum upgrade`. The repository takes care of that for you, as well as any dependencies the software may entertain with other libraries.

RPM Packages installed manually (even with `yum`, which then only acts as an installer) will have to be managed manually as well.

Since the MySQL RPM package shows no dependencies (as far as I can tell from the manual), you are safe from this side.

And to answer your question: the best method is to stick with the versions from the repository. If you *need* a newer version, then you took the right path.

Answer (score 14):

Just this week (2013-10-28), MySQL announced official yum repositories for MySQL Community Edition. The packages are intended for use with RHEL-compatible Linux (e.g. CentOS).

All the details including how to set up the yum repo on your system, can be found from the announcement:

http://insidemysql.com/announcing-new-yum-repositories-for-mysql/

Answer (score 8):

I am no guru myself but I was happy with the result of the RPM method you mentioned since other times I have seen problems with mysql-libs being a dependency for other packages.

(depending on the 5.6 version you want and cpu)

```
mkdir MySQL
cd MySQL
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/MySQL-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
tar -xvf MySQL-5.6.16-1.el6.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
yum install MySQL*rpm
```

installs them in the correct order and removes mysql-libs in one step without conflicts.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-rpm.html

Comment: Tried this on `centos 6.5` and looks like it failed to install `MySQL-server.x86_64 0:5.6.16-1.el6`, http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=nUB6imbf but running mysql -V does output `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.16`.

Comment: Turns out running `sudo yum remove mysql-server` and manually installing it again with downloaded rpm succeeded. Service isn't starting anymore thought, but it may not be hard to fix.

Comment: It's working fine now, I checked in the logs and had to run `mysql_upgrade --port=3306 --user=root --password=PASSWORD`, started service again and everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't surprise me that MySQL is a bit behind.  Why would Oracle make it easy for you to not use pay-for Oracle? </rant>

Anyway, you can get the awkwardly named, but otherwise identical [MariaDB to run easily by adding a new YUM repository.](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/)

Comment: Always get nervous with all these one-off repos.  Am I better off just using the rpm off of MySQL's site?

Comment: This is hardly one-off.  This is Marty's (the main MySQL developer, before MySQL was sold to Sun) follow on, which has been adopted by RedHat for Fedora and RHEL going forward.

Comment: It appears that MariaDB is a fork of MySQL.  Maybe better, I don't know, but not MySQL.  Right?

Comment: Pedantically true, but practically irrelevant (for the moment).  I recently prototyped replacing a MySQL 5.1 install to MariaDB 5.5 for our enterprise application server (in our case, Cent 5) and found no compatibility issues.  It may matter only if this is for something other than a project you're doing yourself and have some really strict release procedures.

Comment: You misunderstand what is happening here. This is the Red Hat philosophy, not Oracle's decision. When Red Hat releases a major package like MySQL 5.1 or PHP 5.3, they typically stick with this major-minor version because it's *stable*. Security fixes, and some bug fixes are backported by Red Hat engineers into MySQL 5.1. If they were constantly tracking the MySQL versions (5.5, then 5.6 and soon 5.7) the RHEL engineers would have to recompile huge swaths of software, which inevitably leads to problems and instability. Users who want new software change can roll their own, use Fedora, etc.

Comment: The OP is asking about Cent (which has a slightly more heatseaker tolerance), not RHEL, so I don't think I misunderstand.  Anyway, I have seen more stability issues with RHEL than I ever had with a properly patched heatseaker like Ubuntu.  At the heart of it, this is why "what is best" questions (and answers I suppose) are frowned upon on SO; what is best for one is not necessarily best for another.

Answer (score -1):

You can install MySQL 5.5 (mysql55-server.x86_64) from IUS repository (currently version 5.5.34 available)