# How to install mysql 5.5 on Azure VM CentOS

Tags: mysql, azure, centos, azure-virtual-machine

have been trying to install MySQL 5.5 on OpenLogic Centos VM on Windows Azure but it keeps failing saying dependency failure.

Tried using remi repo with no luck.

Would like to have suggestions to get MySQL 5.5 installed on CentOS VM on Windows Azure

**Commands RUN -**

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install mysql mysql-server
```

**OUTPUT -**

```
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.5.33-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = 5.5.33-1.el6.remi for package: mysql-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.33-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: mysql-server-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.1.67-1.el6_3 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.33-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.33-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.013-3.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-mysql51.x86_64 0:5.1.54-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.33-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-server-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-server-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Could you post your entire error and the steps that you are going through to install?  This question might also be better served on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few dependencies that you need to get it running.

**Remi Dependency on CentOS 6 and Red Hat (RHEL) 6**

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

**Install MySQL server**

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install mysql mysql-server
```

Check out [Update MySQL version from 5.1 to 5.5 in CentOS 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361720/update-mysql-version-from-5-1-to-5-5-in-centos-6-2/9362289#9362289) as well.

Comment: These are the same commands that were tried earlier, which did not help.