# Upgrading MySQL on RedHat 6.5

Tags: mysql-python, redhat, rhel, system-administration

I have a fresh (clean slate) VM with RHEL 6.5 installed. I've been trying to upgrade MySQL 5.1 that comes with it by following [one of the resources](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/mysql55/) that I found online. But, when I try to install Django and it's MySQLdb library per instruction on [this RedHat's blog post], I run into conflict as copied below:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mysql55 conflicts with mysql-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64
Error: mysql55-libs conflicts with mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64
```

I've asked around online for help regarding this issue. But being a novice (i.e. inexperienced with sysadmin skills), I find it difficult to figure out how to fix it. If anyone could suggest me ways to overcome this trouble, that'd be greatly helpful. Please feel free to ask me extra info that you may need to help me. I'll be checking this post regularly. Thank you.

p.s. All I want is a web server running with Django and MySQL. I've got both Django and Apache installed. It's MySQLdb installation that is causing the trouble.

Comment: The link to the RedHat blog post is missing. Which package did you try to install? Was it MySQL-python?

Comment: Hi @Jens, I followed the one by [webtatic](http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm). I got it installed, but then I tried installing MySQLdb by using the instruction in the latter part of [this blog](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/02/14/setting-up-django-and-python-2-7-on-red-hat-enterprise-6-the-easy-way/). That's when I got the error above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And the error occurs when you enter `sudo yum install gcc mysql-devel`? Because then I would think that mysql-devel depends on mysql51. But I don't know the mysql55 rpm you are using (the one by webtatic). I think it would be easier to install the rpms you can download from Oracle's website (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html).

Comment: Yeah, it happens when I typed that command. I actually used "webtatic" one because it seems to have the simplest instruction. As I said, I'm not experienced with this sort of stuff. After that error happened, I wiped out the installed mysql with `yum remove mysql mysql-*` as described in this [StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361720/update-mysql-version-from-5-1-to-5-5-in-centos-6-2). Are you recommending me to do a fresh install or upgrade MySQL? Upgrading, based on glancing at Oracle's site, is a complicated process. Do you have any more specific direction? Thank you.

Comment: If you have no data in your database, it would be easier to do a fresh installation. If you have some data and downtime is not an issue, you could dump the data, do a fresh installation and import the dump. But I think you will need the mysql-devel rpm for MySQL 55. You find them among the other downloads on the Oracle website.

Comment: I do not have any data and am ready to wipe everything out and start from fresh. Do you think `yum remove mysql mysql-*` is enough to wipe everything related to MySQL or should I do something else? Regarding the RPM from Oracle, I found [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/). Do you think that has the mysql-devel rpm as well? Sorry if this question sounds stupid. As said above, I'm really new to this whole repo/rpm stuff. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can remove everything, follow the instructions you found and afterwards be able to install all MySQL packages. The first rpm only contains the repository data, which points to e.g. http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.5-community/el/6/x86_64/. There you see that the devel-packages are also present.