# Zpanel error after updating MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, vps, zpanel, sentora

When I installed Zpanel on my VPS server (Centos 6, 32bit), the mysql was 5.1. I updated the mysql using the tutorial: [Update MySQL version from 5.1 to 5.5 in CentOS 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361720/update-mysql-version-from-5-1-to-5-5-in-centos-6-2)

But after updating, i'm not able to open zpanel. I am getting this error
[image]

Comment: Have you try to connect mysql using cli ?

Comment: try to connect mysql using command line and see all your credential are working fine.  follow this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial

Comment: ok. If connecting, what should i do? I think zpanel has lost password after updating mysql

Comment: get the mysql log file and check the error

Comment: in your zpanel

this is because you need to tell zpanel new mysql root password. Change the password in these files:

vi /etc/zpanel/panel/cnf/db.php
vi /etc/zpanel/configs/proftpd/proftpd-mysql.conf